# Data Access Application Block Configaration settings

Tags: enterprise-library-5, data-access-app-block

I am using DAAB 5.0 in my WCF application, I need to add the following code in my Web.Config for DAAB to work

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="defaultConnString" />
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="defaultConnString" connectionString="..."
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

However in higher environament Web.Config is quto generated, So I am manually pasting the config section in the Web.Config

> Is there any alternative to have config section in a differrent file?